Integrating to get the phonon density of states from dispersion
I'm looking to calculate the phonon density of states $g(\omega)$from a known functional form for the phonon dispersion $\omega(\vec{K})$ for a monatomic BCC lattice.  I've arrived at the $\omega(\vec{K})$ using the dynamical matrix method outlined in Lattice Dynamics of BCC Titanium (K. COLAKOGLU 2000). My integration method is taking too long, and I'm looking for help on ways to improve my approach.
The method to calculate the $g(\omega)$ is to perform the following integral
$$ g(\omega)\propto\oint{\frac{dS{_\omega}}{v{_g}}}$$
where $v{_g}$ is the energy-dependent group velocity ($v{_g}=|\vec{\nabla}{_K}\omega(\vec{K})|$), and the integral is performed in $K$-space over the surface of constant energy.  The functional form for $\omega(\vec{K})$ is quite complicated, since the method goes out to third nearest neighbor.  Also, $\omega(\vec{K})$ has three components, corresponding to the three polarizations of the phonons.
(* Set up the dynamical matrix *)
D0 = \[Alpha]1 8/3*(1 - C1 C2 C3) //. {C1 -> Cos[kx a/2], 
C2 -> Cos[ky a/2], C3 -> Cos[kz a/2]};

{D11, D22, D33, D12, D13, D23} =
{D0 + 4 \[Alpha]2 S1^2 + 2 \[Alpha]3 (2 - C21 C22 - C21 C23),
D0 + 4 \[Alpha]2 S2^2 + 2 \[Alpha]3 (2 - C22 C23 - C22 C21),
D0 + 4 \[Alpha]2 S3^2 + 2 \[Alpha]3 (2 - C23 C21 - C23 C22),
\[Alpha]1 8/3 S1 S2 C3 + 2 \[Alpha]3 S21 S22,
\[Alpha]1 8/3 S1 S3 C2 + 2 \[Alpha]3 S22 S23,
\[Alpha]1 8/3 S2 S1 C3 + 2 \[Alpha]3 S21 S23} //.
{C1 -> Cos[kx a/2], C2 -> Cos[ky a/2], C3 -> Cos[kz a/2],
S1 -> Sin[kx a/2], S2 -> Sin[ky a/2], S3 -> Sin[kz a/2],
C21 -> Cos[kx a], C22 -> Cos[ky a], C23 -> Cos[kz a],
S21 -> Sin[kx a], S22 -> Sin[ky a], S23 -> Sin[kz a]
};

Dmat = {{D11, D12, D13}, {D12, D22, D23}, {D13, D23, D33}};

(* Solve the dynamical matrix Dmat *)
w2slns = 
Solve[Det[Dmat - IdentityMatrix[3]*M*w2] == 
 0, w2][[;; , 1, 2]];

wslns = Sqrt[w2slns];

(* substitute in parameters for unit cell, mass, bond strength *)
subs = {a -> 1, M -> 30, \[Alpha]1 -> 5000, \[Alpha]2 -> 3000, \[Alpha]3 -> 1000};
wslns = wslns//.subs 

(* absgrad is the group velocity *)
grad = D[#, {{kx, ky, kz}}] & /@ wslns;
absgrad = Norm[#] & /@ grad;

(* Perform the integral for polarization n *)
dos[w_,n_] := 
NIntegrate[1./absgrad[[n]]
 , Element[{kx, ky, kz}
  , ImplicitRegion[Re[wslns[[n]]] == w, {kx, ky, kz}]]]

Mathematica can't seem to evaluate dos[w,1] for any energy value.
No error is given.  The program simply runs for >20 minutes.
I haven't actually waited any longer, but it is impractical to attempt this problem if it takes more than 20 minutes per energy value, per polarization.
Possible issue:  wslns has a small imaginary component.  Hence the Re[] command
I've tried to improve speed by first executing wslns = Simplify[wslns], but this command runs forever, without error.
Does anyone have any ideas as to how I might improve the integration?  I've thought about extracting values and integrating an InterpolationFunction, but I'm not sure how I can achieve that practically.  Thanks for your time.

It is not clear why in you code there is //. instead of /.?

@AlexTrounev It's repeated substitution instead of just regular substitution.  I could have used /.
