Techniques for NIntegrate on a 3D surface region
I'm looking for ways to speed up NIntegrate[] on a region.  My application involves a humongous expression obtained from diagonalizing a 3x3 matrix (see Lattice Dynamics of BCC Titanium (K. COLAKOGLU 2000)), but I'll present a simplified version of the function.
Statement of Problem
The region is a 3D surface defined by
$$
\omega(k_x,k_y,k_z)= \sqrt{4 - \cos(k_x - k_y - k_z) - \cos(k_x + k_y - k_z) - \cos(k_x - k_y + k_z) - \cos(k_x + k_y + k_z)}
$$
and bounded by a rhombic dodecahedron.
The function I want to integrate is the inverse gradient of $\omega(k_x,k_y,k_z)$, i.e. $f(k_x,k_y,k_z)= \frac{1}{\left|\vec{\nabla}_{k}\omega(k_x,k_y,k_z)\right|}$.  For $\omega$ given above, this becomes
$$
f(k_x,k_y,k_z) =
$$
$$
 \frac{\sqrt{1 - \cos(k_x)\cos(k_y)\cos(k_z)}}{\sqrt{\cos^2(k_x)\cos^2(k_z)\sin^2(k_y)+\cos^2(k_x)\cos^2(k_y)\sin^2(k_z)+\cos^2(k_y)\cos^2(k_z)\sin^2(k_x)}}
$$
Attempt at a solution
Below is my code.  The NIntegrate[] command at the end is the one that is giving me trouble.
(* Define base function *)
\[Omega]slns = Sqrt[
 4 - Cos[kx - ky - kz] - Cos[kx + ky - kz] - Cos[kx - ky + kz] - 
  Cos[kx + ky + kz]]

(* Define region.  Start with MMA's built-in region function *)
reg0 = PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "RegionFunction"];

(* Scale and rotate the region to match the function *)
scale0 = 2/(\[Pi] \[Sqrt]3);
reg = Simplify[
   reg0[\[Sqrt]2/2*scale0 (kx + ky), \[Sqrt]2/2*scale0 (-kx + ky), 
    kz*scale0]];

(* Create the smallest unique region.  This is one forty-eighth of the full region *)
regsmall = kx > 0 && ky > 0 && kz > 0 && reg && ky < kx && kz > kx;

(* Create region plots for visualizing *)
regplot = 
  RegionPlot3D[
   reg, {kx, - \[Pi], \[Pi]}, {ky, - \[Pi], \[Pi]}, {kz, - \[Pi], \
\[Pi]}
   , Mesh -> None
   , PlotPoints -> 70
   , MaxRecursion -> 10
   , PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[.4]]];

regplotsmall = 
  RegionPlot3D[
   regsmall, {kx, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {ky, -\[Pi], 
    \[Pi]}, {kz, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Purple, Opacity[.7]]];

(* Check the result. *)
(* First check the full region *)
Show[{
  ContourPlot3D[\[Omega]slns
   , {kx, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {ky, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {kz, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}
   , Contours -> {.5}
   , ContourStyle -> {Opacity[1]}]
  , regplot
  , regplotsmall}
 , PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {-\[Pi], 
    \[Pi]}}
 , Ticks -> {{-\[Pi], 0, \[Pi]}, {-\[Pi], 0, \[Pi]}, {-\[Pi], 
    0, \[Pi]}}
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]

(* Then check the smallest unique region *)
Show[{
  ContourPlot3D[\[Omega]slns
   , {kx, 0, \[Pi]}, {ky, 0, \[Pi]}, {kz, 0, \[Pi]}
   , Contours -> {.5}
   , ContourStyle -> {Opacity[1]}]
  , regplot
  , regplotsmall}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, \[Pi]}, {0, \[Pi]}, {0, \[Pi]}}
 , Ticks -> {{0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, {0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, {0, \[Pi]/
     2, \[Pi]}}
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]

(* Then check the contours of the \[Omega] function in the full region *)
ContourPlot3D[\[Omega]slns
 , {kx, ky, kz} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[reg, {kx, ky, kz}]
 (*,{kx,-\[Pi],\[Pi]},{ky,-\[Pi],\[Pi]},{kz,-\[Pi],\[Pi]}*)
 , Contours -> {.5, 1, 1.5, 2.1, 2.5}
 , ContourStyle -> {Opacity[1], Opacity[.5], Opacity[.3], Opacity[.2],
    Opacity[.1]}]




The rhombic dodecahedron defines the smallest tile-able volume that contains a single core site of the function $\omega$.  This is desired. Notice the faces of the region are normal to the bisectors between neighboring core sites.
The smaller unique region is one-sixth of the octant, as desired.  I can integrate over this region and multiply by 48 to get the correct result.
The function $\omega$ displays symmetry in the full region, as desired. The goal of this code is to pick a surface of constant $\omega$, and integrate the area of that surface weighted by the inverse gradient of $\omega$ along that surface.
Continuing with the code...
(* Create the integrand *)
grad = Simplify[D[\[Omega]slns, {{kx, ky, kz}}]
   , Assumptions -> {-\[Pi] < kx < \[Pi], -\[Pi] < 
      ky < \[Pi], -\[Pi] < kz < \[Pi]}];

absgrad = Simplify[Norm[grad]
   , Assumptions -> {-\[Pi] < kx < \[Pi], -\[Pi] < 
      ky < \[Pi], -\[Pi] < kz < \[Pi]}];

invgrad = Simplify[ComplexExpand[(1./absgrad)]
   , Assumptions -> {-\[Pi] < kx < \[Pi], -\[Pi] < 
      ky < \[Pi], -\[Pi] < kz < \[Pi]}];

(* Execute integration *)
Timing[NIntegrate[
  invgrad, {kx, ky, kz} \[Element] 
   DiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[regsmall && Re[\[Omega]slns] == 1, {kx, ky, kz}]]]]

Results
This returns {4.60938, 0.113875}.  4.6 seconds per point is not too bad, but for the actual function I'll use, this ends up using this taking about 60 seconds (and I need to pick about 150 points).  I'd like to speed up this process.
Other attempts
I tried creating interpolating functions for $\omega$ and $f$, and using them in the NIntegrate[] command
(* Create Random array from \[Omega]slns and invgrad, within smallest unique region. *)
(* Pick number of points *)

Print[Dynamic[kp]];
kcount = 4000;
kp = 0;

(* Randomly pick points from region *)
(* First do the integrand *)
tab1 = Table[kp++;
   {k1, k2, k3} = pt;
   {pt, Re[invgrad] //. {kx -> k1, ky -> k2, kz -> k3}}, {pt, 
    RandomPoint[ImplicitRegion[regsmall, {kx, ky, kz}], kcount]}];
tab1 = Prepend[
   tab1, {{0, 0, 0}, invgrad /. {kx -> .001, ky -> .001, kz -> .001}}];

(* Then do the boundary *)
tabw1 = Table[kp++;
   {k1, k2, k3} = pt;
   {pt, Re[\[Omega]slns] //. {kx -> k1, ky -> k2, kz -> k3}}, {pt, 
    RandomPoint[ImplicitRegion[regsmall, {kx, ky, kz}], kcount]}];
tabw1 = Prepend[tabw1, {{0, 0, 0}, 0}];

(* Create interpolating functions *)
intfuncs = Interpolation[tab1];
intfuncsw = Interpolation[tabw1];

(* Do the integral *)
Timing[NIntegrate[
  intfuncs[kx, ky, kz], {kx, ky, kz} \[Element] 
   DiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[regsmall && Re[\[Omega]slns] == 1, {kx, ky, kz}]]]]


This returns {2.51563, 0.116693}.  This is better, but still not great.
I tried using the interpolating function intfuncsw to define the region of integration, but this just crashes MMA.  Maybe there's some way to do this that I'm missing.
I'd appreciate any advice on how to improve this calculation.
Cheers! Paul

So, DiscretizeRegion seems to be the bottleneck. Meshing is a difficult task, but for some reason DiscretizeRegion has a particular difficulty with this mesh. Maybe it is due to the inequality constraints; these define a convex polytope with sharp cornes, something that ImplicitRegion might not like.
Having found the bottleneck, we need a way to circumvent it. The implicit surfaces for the values of c of interest seem to be regular in the sense that the gradient does not vanish on the surface. Thus, the level sets depend continuously on c and in particular, cannot change topology. Thus, we can try to reuse the mesh topology when changing c only slightly. The new vertex positions can be obtained by Newton's method, using the old vertex positions as starting condition. In fact, we need not even a very accurate representation of the level set of c to begin with; we can also start by a sphere. A high quality mesh for a sphere is easy to get.
sphere = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.000001];

Next we set up Newton's method. First a couple of compiled helper functions:
(*Squaring avoids problems with Sqrt.*)
\[Omega]Squared = 
  X |-> 4 - Cos[Indexed[X, {1}] - Indexed[X, {2}] - Indexed[X, {3}]] -
     Cos[Indexed[X, {1}] + Indexed[X, {2}] - Indexed[X, {3}]] - 
    Cos[Indexed[X, {1}] - Indexed[X, {2}] + Indexed[X, {3}]] - 
    Cos[Indexed[X, {1}] + Indexed[X, {2}] + Indexed[X, {3}]];

Block[{X, XX, c},
  XX = {Compile`GetElement[X, 1], Compile`GetElement[X, 2], 
    Compile`GetElement[X, 3]};
  
  D\[Omega]Squared[X_] = D[\[Omega]Squared[XX], {XX, 1}];
  
  (*Compile \[Omega]Squared.*)
  c\[Omega]Squared = With[{
     code = \[Omega]Squared[XX]
     },
    Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
     ]
    ];
  
  
  D\[Omega][X_] = 
   D[Sqrt[\[Omega]Squared[X]], {{Indexed[X, 1], Indexed[X, 2], 
      Indexed[X, 3]}, 1}];
  
  f[X_] = Together[1/Sqrt[D\[Omega][X] . D\[Omega][X]]];
  
  (*Compile the integrant.*)
  cf = With[{code = f[XX]},
    Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
     ]
    ];
  
  (*Compile the Newton iteration.*)
  cNewtonStep = With[{
     code = 
      XX - ( \[Omega]Squared[XX] - 
          c) (PseudoInverse[{D\[Omega]Squared[XX]}] /. 
           Conjugate -> Identity)[[All, 1]]
     },
    Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}, {c, _Real}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
     ]
    ];
  
  ];

(*Compile the function that maps a triple of points to the area of \
the triangle spanned by them.*)
Block[{X, XX, P, PP},
  
  PP = Table[Compile`GetElement[P, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
  
  carea = 
   With[{code = 
      Sqrt[Dot[#, #]] &[
       Cross[PP[[2]] - PP[[1]], PP[[3]] - PP[[1]]]]},
    Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
     ]
    ];
  ];

step[c_] := X |-> cNewtonStep[X, c];

Now let's get an initial levelset, using a scaled sphere as initial guess.
sphere = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.000001];

x0 = 1.5 MeshCoordinates[sphere];
triangles = MeshCells[sphere, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
"vertex count" -> Length[x0]
"triangle count" -> Length[triangles]
c0 = Sqrt[Mean[c\[Omega]Squared[x0]]];

surfaces = Association[];
surfaces[c0] = 
  FixedPoint[x |-> (step[c0^2] /@ x), x0, 
   SameTest -> (Max[Abs[#1 - #2]] < 1*^-14 &)];

surface = MeshRegion[surfaces[[1]], Triangle[triangles]]


"vertex count" -> 43322
"triangle count" -> 86640


Note that we stored the vertex coordinates of this surface in the Association surfaces under the key c0. The next function will try to look up the surface closest to the value c and use that surface as initial guess for the level set of c.
createNewSurface[c_] := Module[{cinit},
   (*Find the closest value of c that we have meshed already.*)
   cinit = Nearest[Keys[surfaces], c][[1]];
   
   (*Use the vertex coordinates as initial value for Newton's method*)
   surfaces[c] = FixedPoint[
     x |-> (step[c^2] /@ x), surfaces[cinit], 
     SameTest -> (Max[Abs[#1 - #2]] < 1*^-12 &)
     ];
   ];

Now vertex coordinates for values of c close to c0 can be obtained quite quickly:
createNewSurface[c0 0.9]; // AbsoluteTiming
createNewSurface[c0 0.8]; // AbsoluteTiming
createNewSurface[c0 1.1]; // AbsoluteTiming
createNewSurface[c0 1.2]; // AbsoluteTiming


{0.180946, Null}
{0.162472, Null}
{0.223132, Null}
{0.387845, Null}

The following takes the coordinate matrix x, assumes that it represents a mesh with triangles given by triangles and integrates the piecewise-linear interpolation of the function cf along that mesh.
int[x_] := Module[{trianglecoords, areas, fvalues},
   trianglecoords = Partition[x[[Flatten[triangles]]], 3];
   areas = carea[trianglecoords];
   fvalues = cf[x];
   Mean[areas . Partition[fvalues[[Flatten[triangles]]], 3]]
   ];

So the integrals of all the surfaces can be obtain like this:
integrals = int /@ surfaces

<|1.78992 -> 80.0074, 1.61093 -> 46.8327, 1.43194 -> 30.1202,
1.96891 -> 223.636, 2.1479 -> 40905.|>

This will of course only work for such regular values of c. And it may also run into some problems when c approaches an irregular value. This may be mended a little, by approching such difficult values only slowly, so that there are already good approximations in the list surfaces.

This seems to work.  This level of Mathematica is above my understanding, but the result checks out against expected trends.  Thank you for your help.

Since your integration is over a surface, this constraint allows the integrand to be further simplified to
$$
f(k_x,k_y,k_z)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin ^2(k_x)\cos ^2(k_y)\cos^2(k_z)+\cos ^2(k_x) \sin ^2(k_y) \cos ^2(k_z)+\cos ^2(k_x)\cos ^2(k_y)\sin ^2(k_z)}}
$$
Then I tried compiling the integrand.
\[Omega]slns2 = 
  4 - Cos[kx - ky - kz] - Cos[kx + ky - kz] - Cos[kx - ky + kz] - 
   Cos[kx + ky + kz];
reg0 = PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "RegionFunction"];
(*Scale and rotate the region to match the function*)
scale0 = 2/(\[Pi]  \[Sqrt]3);
reg = Simplify[
   reg0[\[Sqrt]2/2*scale0  (kx + ky), \[Sqrt]2/2*scale0  (-kx + ky), 
    kz*scale0]];

(*Create the smallest unique region.This is one forty-eighth of the \
full region*)
regsmall = kx > 0 && ky > 0 && kz > 0 && reg && ky < kx && kz > kx;
cf = Compile[{{kx, _Real}, {ky, _Real}, {kz, _Real}}, 
   1/(2  \[Sqrt](Cos[kx]^2  Cos[kz]^2  Sin[ky]^2 + 
         Cos[ky]^2  (Cos[kz]^2  Sin[kx]^2 + Cos[kx]^2  Sin[kz]^2)))];
f[kx_?NumericQ, ky_?NumericQ, kz_?NumericQ] := cf[kx, ky, kz]
AbsoluteTiming[
 NIntegrate[
  f[kx, ky, kz], {kx, ky, kz} \[Element] 
   DiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[regsmall && \[Omega]slns2 == 1, {kx, ky, kz}]]]]

(*{0.2727484`,0.11387271860647907`}*)

On my computer, without compiling, the calculation takes 5 seconds. It's much faster now.

Thanks @houzw!  This is a great tip.  I'm not sure that your simplification of the integrand is valid, but regardless this may help immensely.

I obtain similar results on my machine.  I'm quite certain the simplification you applied to the integrand is not valid, but that doesn't significantly change the speed gain.  Is it possible to compile the discretized region?  I'm finding with my humongous expression for '[Omega]', it still takes about 55 seconds per point.  I think that time is spent mostly in the 'DiscretizeRegion[]' function.   The full expression can be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/304965/integrating-to-get-the-phonon-density-of-states-from-dispersion

@BohemianTapestry I don't understand what you mean by not valid. If it's wrong, why do they get the same results? DiscretizeRegion is not fast, and from my testing, compiling it makes it even slower. For me, taking a minute to get one point is not unacceptable. If you have many points to calculate, parallelization may be a good choice.

What I mean is the expression you provide for f is not equivalent to the expression I provide for f.  In any case, you are correct that I can parallelize the process.  It turns out that for the largest values of \[Omega], the integration takes much much longer.  I'm not sure if it's a process with discretizeregion or nintegrate.

@BohemianTapestryBO They are equal on the integration surface, and that is enough.

No, DiscretizeRegion is not compilable; I think (actually, I hope!) it already has a compiled backend.
